# How to add an activity when user swipes to the next page of the notification in Android Wear?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I need to implement an activity to show some list of items when user swipes to the next page of the notification in Android Wear.How is it possible ?

Now we can add the buttons on the added pages of notification.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `setDisplayIntent`, providing the `PendingIntent` of the Activity you want to start, to the `WearableExtender`. E.g.

```
wearableExtender.setDisplayIntent(activityPendingIntent);
wearableExtender.setCustomSizePreset(Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN);
```

the second line is needed to show the Activity full screen

Comment: I doing WearableExtender on handheld side.
i have given a button on second page of notification.When i click on that button i call a class and send the datas to  android wear.In the listner  class i doing the some method.This class is in Android Wear.So which class i use in this wearableExtender.setDisplayIntent(activityPendingIntent);

Comment: *Actually i have given a button on second page of notification*: Do you mean an `action`? *hen i click on that button i call a class and doing the same method*: Which one are you calling? Would you mind posting the code that is not working ?